# Which data type to use when using huge fractions?

Tags: java, floating-accuracy

I am working on an NLP project and am supposed to compute this expression:

> freq=1/345128

I am using float and double and it is reading it as 0.0, which does not help me as I want the exact number to at least 6 decimal places.

Earlier when I was doing it, I just multiplied the number by 10^6 since I was just comparing two values. However it is different now, and I need the exact numbers. Is there any work around available which I can use.

Comment: [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that `a` is an integer variable, which means that your code is using integer division (that truncates the result). If that's the case, you need to turn the expression into a floating-point division:

```
freq = a / 345128.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the numerator or denominator as double.

```
public class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double freq=1d/345128d;
        System.out.println(freq);
    }
}
```